# Number of wheels

Tags: combinatorics

It is a classical combinatorial problem to count the number of wheels with n black or white points under rotation (action of the group $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} n$). It can be modeled as orbits under the action of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} n$ on $\{0,1,...,n-1 \}$ mapping to $\{0,1 \}$ (black or white).
Is the following problem considered somewhere and is there a nice closed formula?
This time we have more than one wheel where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts simultaously. A model should look as follows:
Let $n_1 , ... , n_l \geq 1$ be natrual numbers and let $k:=$smallest common multiple of those integers. Then $\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}k$ acts on $\{0,1,...,n_1 -1 \} \times ... \times \{0,1,...,n_l-1 \}$ mapping to $\{0,1 \}$ (or we also might look here at more coulours than black or white).
What is the number of orbits?
Exact questions: With the natural action of $G=\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}k$ on $N=\{0,1,...,n_1 -1 \} \times ... \times \{0,1,...,n_l-1 \}$, what is the number of orbits of the induced action of $G$ on $Hom(N, \{0,1 \})$ (or more generaly $Hom( N, \{0,1,...,r \})$?
(The case $l=1$ corresponds to the classical case of one wheel and $l \geq 1$ should model the case of several wheels with black or white points which are rotated simultanously by the action)

Comment: It is difficult to follow what your exact question is, but it appears that you are asking for a reference to [burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma).

Comment: I added some more things, this lemma does not make it look too easy to get an explicit formula directly.

Comment: I agree with @JMoravitz that this question is a bit unclear.  Are you asking about [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29)?

Comment: The case of one necklace as in the link corresponds to l=1. At the end of my questions , I tried to make it mathematicaly precise.

Answer (score 1):

With this problem  we start by enumeration in order to  get an idea of
the task  at hand and also obtain some backup  data to help  verify an
eventual solution. We evidently require  the cycle index of the cyclic
group generated by  the set of cycles or wheels  that are given, which
form the decomposition into disjoint cycles of a permutation, which we
shall call  $\alpha$.  Enumeration is  very simple here, we  apply the
single rotation to the  data $k$ times (with $k=\mathrm{LCM}(n_1, n_2,
\ldots, n_\ell)$) and factor all  of the results into cycles.  Add and
divide by  $k$ to get  the cycle index  that answers the  problem.  We
check these by computing some singleton cycle indices (i.e.  $\ell=1$)
which have the well-known closed form. We get e.g.

$$Z(C_6) = 1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}+1/6\,{a_{{2}}}^{3}
+1/3\,{a_{{3}}}^{2}+1/3\,a_{{6}}$$

and

$$Z(C_8) = 1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{4}
+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{2}+1/2\,a_{{8}}$$

and we see that the routine  is working. We can now compute some cycle
indices for  groups generated by  permutations that contain  more than
one cycle. E.g. we obtain (subscript gives lengths of cycles)

$$Z(C_{2,3}) = 
1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}+1/6\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/3\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}
+1/3\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}$$

or

$$Z(C_{4,6,12}) =
1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{22}+1/12\,{a_{{2}}}^{8}{a_{{1}}}^{6}
+1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{6}
\\+1/6\,{a_{{4}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{3}
+1/6\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{a_{{6}}}^{2}
+1/3\,a_{{4}}a_{{6}}a_{{12}}$$

or finally

$$Z(C_{5,10}) =
1/10\,{a_{{1}}}^{15}+1/10\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{5}
+2/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{3}+2/5\,a_{{5}}a_{{10}}.$$

At  this point we  consult the  experts and  discover a  simple indeed
nearly trivial  formula that even though  it iterates over  the set of
rotations ($k$ iterations) does not involve factoring permutations and
works  with basic  arithmetic.  In  fact on  page 163  section  7.2 of
Harary and Palmer's *Graphical Enumeration* we find the formula

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\Large 
\frac{1}{k} \sum_{q=1}^k \prod_{p=1}^\ell
a_{n_p/\gcd(q, n_p).}^{\gcd(q, n_p)}}$$

The proof of  this is immediate. The value $q$  indicates how often we
have  traversed the  directed arcs  of the  cycles of  the permutation
$\alpha,$  completing  several  traversals  of  individual  cycles  if
necessary until  everyone is  back at the  start position at  the same
time. The  value of  $\gcd(q, n_p)$ tells  us what  the GCD is  of the
current position  (corresponding to $q$)  and the length $n_p$  of the
cycle $p.$ This has the effect  of only retaining the position on $p$,
discarding  any  contribution   from  eventual  prior  rotations  that
completed some number of entire traversals of cycle $p.$ This is as it
should be as a cycle does  not remember the history of its traversals,
only the current  position. The rest is simple.   The cycle $p$ splits
into a set of cycles (possibly  a singleton). The GCD gives the number
of elements in this set and hence $n_p/\gcd(q, n_p)$ their length. The
sub-cycles are obtained from one  another by the rotation that takes a
slot to  the one adjacent  to it and  repeat after GCD  steps. Observe
that when we have a single cycle of length $m$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{q=1}^m a_{m/\gcd(q,m)}^{\gcd(q,m)}
= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{d|m} \sum_{q=1,\gcd(q,m)=d}^m a_{m/d}^d
\\ = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{d|m} a_{m/d}^d
\sum_{q=1,\gcd(q,m/d)=1}^{m/d} 1
= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{d|m} a_{m/d}^d \varphi(m/d)
\\ = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{d|m} \varphi(d) a_{d}^{m/d}$$

which is the usual result. We are now ready to answer the OPs question
concerning colorings  with at most $N$ colors  (colorings with exactly
$N$  colors  are  obtained  from these  by  inclusion-exclusion).   By
Burnside the colors must be constant on the cycles and we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\Large 
\frac{1}{k} \sum_{q=1}^k \prod_{p=1}^\ell
N^{\gcd(q, n_p)}.}$$

We get for three cycles of length two, three and five the closed form

$$1/30\,{N}^{10}+1/30\,{N}^{9}+1/15\,{N}^{8}+1/15\,{N}^{7}
\\+2/15\,{N}^{6}+2/15\,{N}^{5}+{\frac {4\,{N}^{4}}{15}}
+{\frac {4\,{N}^{3}}{15}}$$

which yields the sequence

$$1, 96, 3366, 49920, 424575, 2489760, 11218844, 41564160, 
\\ 132409485, 374149600, 959030754, 2267396352, \ldots$$

Similarly for cycles of length four, six and twelve we obtain

$$1/12\,{N}^{22}+1/12\,{N}^{14}+1/6\,{N}^{10}
\\+1/6\,{N}^{7}+1/6\,{N}^{6}+1/3\,{N}^{3}$$

with the sequence

$$1, 351096, 2615497218, 1466038051520, 198682659520875,
\\ 10968481860668136, 325818477281074596, \ldots$$

The  Maple code  that was  used  to explore  the above  ideas was  the
following.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_cycleind_gcyclicENUM :=
proc(alpha)
option remember;
local res, k, all, src, autom, q, len, rot, cyc, base;

    res := 0; k := lcm(seq(c, c in alpha));
    all := add(c, c in alpha);

    rot := []; base := 1;
    for len in alpha do
        rot :=
        [op(rot), seq(base+p, p=1..len-1), base];
        base := base + len;
    od;

    src := [seq(p, p=1..all)];
    autom := [seq(p, p=1..all)];

    for q to k do
        res := res +
        pet_autom2cycles(src, autom);

        autom :=
        [seq(autom[rot[p]], p=1..all)];
    od;

    res/k;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
n -> add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n))/n;

pet_cycleind_gcyclic :=
proc(alpha)
option remember;
local k, res, len, term, inst, q;

    k := lcm(seq(c, c in alpha));
    res := 0;

    for q to k do
        term := 1;
        for len in alpha do
            inst := gcd(q, len);
            term := term * a[len/inst]^inst;
        od;

        res := res + term;
    od;

    res/k;
end;

COLORS :=
alpha ->
subs([seq(a[q]=N, q=1..add(p, p in alpha))],
     pet_cycleind_gcyclic(alpha));
```